# What does 'cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency' mean while installing eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am trying t install egit plugin in my eclipse . And I get the following errors:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Team Support UI 3.6.201.v20130125-135424 (org.eclipse.team.ui 3.6.201.v20130125-135424)
    Team Support UI 3.6.101.R37x_v20111109-0800 (org.eclipse.team.ui 3.6.101.R37x_v20111109-0800)
    Team Support UI 3.6.100.I20110525-0800 (org.eclipse.team.ui 3.6.100.I20110525-0800)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.2.20120213-0813]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.4.1.201406201815-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Git Team Provider UI 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.team.ui [3.6.200,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.2.20120213-0813 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.team.ui [3.6.101.R37x_v20111109-0800]
```

I am using eclipse indigo on ubuntu 13.04.
How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to install the newest EGit on top of Indigo EE. This is not supported as the newest EGit requires newer Team Provider than can be found in Indigo.

Try installing EGit from the Indigo update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) or upgrade Eclipse.